# XML / C# Loop through nodes of the same name

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML file with keys and values, and I currently loop through the XML doc, and I read all the data.

However, I have certain 'keys' or 'Nodes' that have the same keyname, but different (or same) values.
I need to loop through these same nodes within the same parent node.

```
<tile>
   <x>0</x>
   <y>1</y>
   <name>Grass</name>
   <entity>Tree</entity>
   <entity>Building</entity>
   <entity>Something</entity>
</tile>
<tile>
   <x>1</x>
   <y>2</y>
   <name>Dirt</name>
   <entity>Tree</entity>
   <entity>Building</entity>
</tile>
```

I need to get X, Y and the Name, and an array/list of the entity.
This I need for every Tile in the XML.

So I need to loop through all of the  and get the contents, including a list with the

Current code:

```
        XmlElement element = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nList = element.SelectNodes("/map/tile");
        foreach(XmlNode node in nList){
            int x = int.Parse(node["x"].InnerText);
            int y = int.Parse(node["y"].InnerText);
            String materialName = node["name"].InnerText;
            for(node["entity"] in allEntityNodesWithinThisTile){ }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
string xml = @"<tile>
   <x>0</x>
   <y>1</y>
   <name>Grass</name>
   <entity>Tree</entity>
   <entity>Building</entity>
   <entity>Something</entity>
</tile>";

var data = from t in XElement.Parse(xml).DescendantsAndSelf("tile")
select new {
   X=(int)t.Element("x"),
   Y=(int)t.Element("y"),
   Name=(string)t.Element("name"),
   Entities= t.Elements("entity").Select (x => x.Value)
};
```

Comment: My XML is an actual File (XmlDocument object), not a string

Comment: Then use Load instead of Parse, I added another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = from t in XElement.Load(xmlFileName).DescendantsAndSelf("tile")
select new {
   X=(int)t.Element("x"),
   Y=(int)t.Element("y"),
   Name=(string)t.Element("name"),
   Entities= t.Elements("entity").Select (x => x.Value)
};
```